# Setting Source for Xamarin.Forms VideoPlayer

Tags: video, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I am trying to make my application play youtube playlist videos. I set the Source:

```
           <video:VideoPlayer x:Name="videoPlayer"
                       Grid.Row="0" Source="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jwcgm5VYV-U&list=PLyjPaKJQuCEzqQKdA8FsQdsJ77XbjKkBH" />
```

But got an error:

> Error     '=' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'.

How can I deal with this issue?

Comment: You might need to replace `&` with `&amp;` In your URL

Comment: @CGPA6.4 Thank you! I could run the application now, but the player shows: Error: Unsupported video type or invalid file path.

Maybe it has nothing to do with my original question, or does it?

Comment: I can't say no because we are changing url. Try setting url from code behind & check what happens.

Comment: @CGPA6.4 Same result, so I guess it is not the right way to play a play list  from url. I will create another question. But as you were first who suggested a solution, would you like to make the replacement of & as an answer, so I could mark it as such? I will wait for 15 minutes before marking the answer. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error '=' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'

This is because you are using `&` sign in xaml file which isn't supporting, so replace it to `&amp;`. For more information visit @Paul answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bunch of characters that are illegal in XML properties or texts (XAML is an XML dialect), since they have a special meaning, see [here](https://keylimetie.com/blog/2008/9/25/how-to-safely-escape-invalid-xml-characters/). These are

```
<
>
"
' and
&
```

These characters will have to be escaped by the following sequences

```
< = &lt;
> = &gt;
" = &quot;
' = &apos;
& = &amp;
```

Hence you should change your XAML to

```
<video:VideoPlayer x:Name="videoPlayer"
                   Grid.Row="0" Source="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jwcgm5VYV-U&amp;list=PLyjPaKJQuCEzqQKdA8FsQdsJ77XbjKkBH" />
```

Comment: Thank you! As I mentioned in my comment above, the player now shows:

 Error: Unsupported video type or invalid file path. 

Maybe it has nothing to do with my original question, or does it?

Comment: @DavidShochet Seems to me as if that's an issue with the component and, yes, it seems unrelated to me.

Comment: Thank you very much. I marked CGPA6.4's answer, as he suggested the same first in his comment, but I really appreciate your help.